Unable to use our PowerDNS Nameservers with GoDaddy domains - Error message: "nameserver isn't registered"
We are https://elitedomains.de/, a German domain provider offering nameservers for our customers to use with external domains as well. However, we have encountered an issue when trying to use our nameservers with domains registered at GoDaddy.
When attempting to add one of our nameservers to a GoDaddy-registered domain, we receive the following error message: "We can't save your changes because this nameserver isn't registered. Verify your entry for accuracy and check with your DNS provider that this nameserver is registered."
see screenshot
The records of our nameservers appear to be correct and match those of other nameserver providers, as shown here: https://unboundtest.com/m/A/ns1.elitedomains.de/GDCRCWY2
We initially suspected that the issue might be related to our infrastructure provider, Cloudflare. However, even when setting up an A-record pointing to the IP address of our nameservers on another provider and attempting to add it to a GoDaddy domain, the problem persists.
We wonder if it could be due to our PowerDNS configuration? This is our PowerDNS configuration file: https://justpaste.it/fgh9q
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any insights into what might be causing it? We appreciate any help or suggestions you may have.
Thank you!

I'm having the same problem with Godaddy. The same nameserver works fine with other registrars. I'm about to move all my domains away from Godaddy.

Maybe your glue record is also missing in the zone of the extension. which tld you nameserver domain have?

I have the problem with Godaddy on every TLD. Their solution is to "register" the IP address of nameserver in the "hostnames" tab. "Hostnames
let you use your domain to create custom nameservers that can be used on this and other domains." I guess that's the "glue record". The nameservers I'm attempting to use are with a different registrar. And instead of resolving and creating the glue record for me, GoDaddy forces me to add that "hostname" to make it work. Oh well, it's time to get off.

We solved our problem. Thanks to everybody :)
The glue record was missing in the zone of the extension, i.e. in the zone of the DENIC registry.
